# How can I resume a dd operation after a "error writing in file" status?

Tags: hard-drive, openssl, dd

This command produced the error mentioned above after 9 h (preparing a 2 TB hdd for encryption):

```
time openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom \
bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt </dev/zero \
| pv -bartpes 1884183960000  | dd bs=512 count=1840023391 of=/dev/sdc3
```

I got at 50% (9 h) a total written GB count as well as a bs/count information.

Is it possible to resume this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the `seek=BLOCKS` which should make `dd` start writing at the block next to `BLOCKS` of your disk address space.

Supposedly you should also decrease `count` by that number of blocks as well.

Comment: You again. And another perfect answer for me. TYSM all the best from a German questioner.

Comment: I found another explanation regarding my question to obs/ibs: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108858/seek-argument-in-command-dd What I didn't found was a real difference between bs and obs/ibs together with seek. The man isn't clear frmpov.

Comment: I found something about seek/skip: 
skip=SKIPBLOCKS  | Skip blocks (bs/ibs) of the INPUT-device(!)
seek=SEEKBLOCKS  | Skip blocks (bs/obs) of the OUTPUT-device(!)

Comment: @JohnJane, keep in mind that your source device is not really a device but rather a stream: *skipping* N bytes from it would litreally mean *reading* them (or failing with "blah blah the device is not seekable" -- depending on how smart `dd` is; both cases are unacceptable.  In either case, skipping a part of random input has no sense.  *Seeking* in the destination device, conversely, has sense: it will position the file pointer to the correct address using appropriate syscall.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But I run into the same error after 9 h (50%) again today. Would you do me a favor and try to replicate the dd values to check if I may use/calculated the wrong ones?

Comment: I can post all necessary information of the error, including everything you need (/proc/partition ..).

Comment: Maybe I miss calculated pv and in real it is 100%?

Comment: dd error output: `error writing output file`
`1840023391+0 Datensätze ein` <--100% correct
`1840023391+0 Datensätze aus` <--100% correct
`942091976192 Bytes (942 GB) kopiert, 33610,4 s, 28,0 MB/s`  <--50% BUT the number `942091976192` is exact the multiplication of `512*1840023391`! I feel so stupid. It is in front of me and I can't see it.

Comment: @JohnJane, I may be a bit lost here, but if you're using `seek=N` to make `dd` *continue* writing to the target device, you'll have to decrease its `count` parameter by the value of `N` -- otherwise `dd` will try to write past the end of the device (which is not a regular file and hence can't grow). Is this your problem?

Comment: @JohnJane, you might also have a "not really a problem" problem here: you might for some reason have miscalculated the amount of data to write because different tools might use different units for their display.  For instance, `blockdev --getsz /dev/sdaX` would report the size in units of 512 bytes while the output from `cat /proc/partitions` uses units of 1024. And you see, if the "target" size you've calculated is off by at least a single block, writing that one block will fail. But note that *all the blocks before it have been written* just okay, so no worries here.